# About the compatible Radeon Rx550x for Blender Cycles Render

Tags: gpu, compatibility

I use a laptop with Radeon Rx550X and Intel UHD Graphics 620 on Intel i7-8565U CPU.
However, Blender doesn't recognize both implemented GPUs.
I'm using Blender3.5 and the GPU driver is the newest version 23.4.1.
Is Blender compatible with these GPUs?
I googled compatibility of GPUs and Blender but it seemed no problem (I guess...).

Thanks.